# Clench/clasp something in your fist?

Tags: nouns, american-english

You take something in your hand (e.g. a cross) and then wrap your fingers around it. In other words, you hold the object in your fist. What would be the best way to describe that (in US English)?

- You **clench** the cross in your fist.
- You **clasp** the cross in your fist.
- *Or something entirely different?*

I'd love to hear your suggestions!

**Edit:** One user asked for more context. Although I am actually looking for  a word that would work in all scenarios, I was thinking about a religious person, who clenches (clasps? grasps?) a cross whenever (s)he prays.

Comment: You grasp the cross!

Comment: You clutch the cross!

Comment: Clench is when you hold your fingers in your palm as if to hit someone. So like Josh, grasp is what I would use. "The elephant grasped the branch with its trunk."

Comment: I'm not crazy about 'clasp' or 'grasp', but 'clench' does imply, in my opinion, that you are holding/grasping the object with a lot of force which you may not intend.

Comment: Coil your fingers around the cross.

Comment: I'd suggest 'grip'.

Comment: Voting to close because you haven't given us a sample sentence showing how you'd like to use the word.  I need some context to understand why you have such a death grip on this religious artifact.

Comment: @aparente001 I have updated the question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Is she simply holding it, or holding onto it, or is there some sort of squeezing going on?  Clenching would indicate a great deal of tension in the hand.  What is her emotional state while she is holding it?  Is there some indication that she would be doing something special, beyond ordinary, garden variety "holding"?

Answer (score 5):

There's quite a few English words beginning with /kl/ that will work here.
It turns out that `kl-` is the assonance (initial cluster) that tends to mean 'together'.

51% (43 of 84) of the English [simplex words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Definitions.pdf) beginning with that cluster (mostly spelled 'CL' instead of 'KL') refer to a very primal semantic sense of "contiguous; connect". Of these, at least the following transitive verbs work in this context:

- *clasp, clench, clinch, clutch, clamp, cling (to), cleave (to)*

Many of the words in this class aren't transitive verbs, of course. And there is more than grasping involved.  21 of the 43 'connect' words refer to connection by **impact**, e.g,

- *clamp, clash, clobber, clout, club*

and 11 of **these** refer to **noises** made by such impacts, i.e, actual onomatopoeia. E.g,

- *clap, clomp, clatter, clamor, clink*

It's quite an amazing display of phonosemantics.
In fact, it's clear enough to make a neat [Venn Diagram](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer! Clearly there are many options, but which one do you think would work best (in the context of the question)?

Comment: And, of course, a *cluster* is brought together.

Comment: That is a very interesting paper linked at the bottom. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use *grip* e.g. *I gripped the clutch*.

Comment: "You gripped the clutch"? :) Wouldn't a better example be with an object that itself isn't a synonym for 'grip'? Funny, if that's what you meant though.

Comment: Grip does imply control.